# Has Judas Priest ever performed Jugulator or Demolition tracks with Rob Halford?

Tags: metal

I am a fan of Judas Priest and loved all their albums so far. It took me some time to find out the band has two albums that don't feature original singer Rob Halford. The reason for not finding out soon is because these albums are the only Judas Priest's studio albums not listed on Spotify.
These albums (released in 1997 and 2001 respectively) were recorded with Tim Owens, who joined the band in 1996, after Halford's departure in 1992. In 2003, Judas Priest announced they would reunite with Rob Halford, thus leading to Tim's departure.

The Jugulator and Demolition albuns rely on a more brutal approach (vocally speaking) than any other Judas Priest album, even though Tim was able to sing all the other Priest songs well enough.
The thing is, I searched on YouTube for every song featured in Jugulator and Demolition, to see if I could find a live performance with Rob Halford but I can't find. I even took a look at the [Epitaph World Tour setlist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitaph_World_Tour#Songs_from_each_album) in which they performed at least one song for every album released just to find they didn't include songs from Jugulator and Demolition.
I Googled anything about the reason on why Halford won't sing any of these songs and found nothing. The band don't seem to be "trying to hide" the albums nor they have issues with Tim, who said [in an interwiew](http://www.uberrock.co.uk/interviews/61-october-interviews/12676-tim-ripper-owens-uber-rock-interview-exclusive.html) that he is still friends with the band members, even with Rob Halford. Rob Halford seems to be very confortable with the band's progress while he was away, as we can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbP9zULTT_o).

So, has the band ever performed Jugulator or Demolition tracks live with Rob Halford? Why won't the band include any of these songs on their setlists since Halford's returning? Is Halford unable to properly sing those songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob Halford has never played any of the songs from these two albums with Judas Priest.

Source: http://www.setlist.fm/stats/judas-priest-6bd6bafa.html

Comment: Please explain what your link means. I don't know this website... I don't understand how your link justifies your answer.

Comment: The website essentially acts as a database, holding setlists of all the songs various artists have played over the years. If you click on the individual songs, it drops down with the various places and years those songs have been played. None of the songs from Jugulator or Demolition have been played live apart from between the years of 1998 and 2002 (the years when Rob wasn't in the band)

Comment: @Bebs This answers if they ever performed any of those songs with Rob Halford but it doesn't answer why they don't perform them anymore. Should I mark this as the answer and open a new question to ask why they don't play them anymore? (or perhaps give up on finding the answer, since there are no interviews or such, as pointed by Rahul Kumar on a comment on his answer)

Comment: Would imagine it's just a preference/courtesy thing seeing as he isn't on the albums. Most sets are made up of a combination of new songs & the most popular singles, so chances are they just haven't made the cut

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure Rob Halford has not performed any songs from these two albums and according to me it is because

- Those songs fit more into Tim's range than Rob's.
- Fans prefer Rob over Tim any day.

Comment: Most fans do prefer Rob over Tim, but that doesn't add to anything, since I'm literally asking about Rob singing. Fitting more into Tim's range might not be the reason on why they don't perform them anymore, because Tim had to sing songs that fit more into Rob's range, and Rob made some songs on their own that are more brutal, so the opposite is valid.

Comment: Tim had to perform those songs because those songs define judas priest and the Tim era wasn't the band's hightpoint so.

Comment: I can't help comparing Judas Priest to Nightwish. Nightwish's been through a very similar situation and they remain playing songs from the albums released with Anette Olzon, who has a more pop vocal compared to Tarja Turunen (former vocalist) and Floor Jansen (actual vocalist). Tim's era had it's highs and lows but Turbo received some bad critics, as bad as Demolition and they remain playing some of its songs live (mainly Turbo Lover), so why can't the same be applied to Jugulator and Demolition? I mean, some songs are really appreciated by even the most hardcore Judas fans.

Comment: Maybe Rob does not want to perform those song since he had a falling out from the members of the band before leaving and he simply does not want to revisit those albums.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna doe this answer your question?

Comment: No, not really. These are only assumptions. I too have my own guessings on why they do not play songs from those albums but I expect to get a more accurate answer here.

Comment: well there are no interviews of any sort that can prove anything so we can only speculate